# Way to keybind «» in Emacs

Tags: key-bindings, unicode, characters, insert

I would like to be able to keybind `«` and `»` to easy key bindings.
At the moment in Emacs the only way to write these latin quotation marks is this:

`C-x 8 <` and `C-x 8 >`

I tried the following, but apparently the quotation mark is interpreted as a macro:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-b") "«")
```

I also tried the following:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-M v") (lambda () (insert "«")))
```

...unsuccessfully.

Comment: Just a warning: redefining a key in the global key map should be done with some care. You may think that `C-M-b` (which is by default bound to `backward-sexp`) is not useful (e.g. you may not be a programmer now), but if you do become a programmer later, it will cause problems. It's better to define it in a mode specific key map as you do in your second method: at least that limits the key definition to that mode only.

Comment: You might also look at the [conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html) that Emacs has in place, to make keys available to the user that will not conflict with those of Emacs itself or any third-party packages (assuming that *they* follow the conventions too of course).

Comment: For simple unicode chars like `«`, you may be better off leaving Emacs alone and using input facilities provided by your desktop environment. E.g. I use Gnome and I have defined the `right-ALT` key to be the Compose key, I can enter the opening guillemet with `Compose <<`. This works in *any* program, not just in Emacs and allows you to leave your keymaps in blessed peace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quickly inserting a single Greek letter](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28749/quickly-inserting-a-single-greek-letter)

Comment: @NickD I didn't understand what you meant with leaving Emacs alone? Not using Emacs?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' It worked! If you add as an answer, I will accept. Thanks!

Comment: No, I meant you can solve the problem *below* Emacs: the Compose key method applies to *all* applications, *including* Emacs.

Comment: @Adelita: since the solution described in the linked answer is satisfactory to you, the best thing to do is for you to upvote that answer and close this question  marking it as a duplicate of the linked one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried the following, but apparently the quotation mark is interpreted as a macro: [...]

You’re almost there, « and » are non-ASCII characters with codes above 127, so you have to use vectors instead:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-b") (kbd "«"))
;; likewise for »
```

Comment: +1. Good answer. It might help to point to some doc where non-ASCII > 127 is described, and where there's an explanation of why it's problematic here.

Comment: @Drew The docs for [insert-char](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Insertion#command-insert-char-character-optional-count-inherit) talks about restrictions on non-ASCII characters a little bit.

Comment: @g-gundam: Maybe so. It would still be good to point to that or similar info  in the answer. Comments can be deleted at any time - Q&A need to stand on their own.

Answer (score 0):

The transcript below  defines a keyboard macro, names it and insert it in to the current buffer.  It subsequently it binds the keys `C-M-b` to the newly defined command.

The above procedure would have created

```lisp
(defalias 'my-quote
   (kmacro "C-x 8 <"))
```

for you.

***(I am running `emacs` from git repo. So, it uses `kmacro`.  In your case, it may or may not be different.  The procedure is the same)***

Now `my-quote` is like any other command.  And bind it like you would any other command.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-b") 'my-quote)
```

```
 C-x (           ;; kmacro-start-macro
 C-x 8 <         ;; self-insert-command
 C-x )           ;; kmacro-end-macro
 M-x             ;; execute-extended-command
 n           ;; self-insert-command
 a           ;; self-insert-command
 m           ;; self-insert-command
 e           ;; self-insert-command
 -           ;; self-insert-command
 l           ;; self-insert-command
 a           ;; self-insert-command
 s           ;; self-insert-command
 t           ;; self-insert-command
 -           ;; self-insert-command
 k           ;; self-insert-command
 b           ;; self-insert-command
 d           ;; self-insert-command
 <tab>           ;; minibuffer-complete
 <return>        ;; minibuffer-complete-and-exit
 m           ;; self-insert-command
 y           ;; self-insert-command
 -           ;; self-insert-command
 q           ;; self-insert-command
 u           ;; self-insert-command
 e           ;; self-insert-command
 <backspace>         ;; delete-backward-char
 o           ;; self-insert-command
 t           ;; self-insert-command
 e           ;; self-insert-command
 <return>        ;; exit-minibuffer
 M-x M-x         ;; execute-extended-command
 i           ;; self-insert-command
 n           ;; self-insert-command
 s           ;; self-insert-command
 e           ;; self-insert-command
 r           ;; self-insert-command
 t           ;; self-insert-command
 -           ;; self-insert-command
 k           ;; self-insert-command
 b           ;; self-insert-command
 d           ;; self-insert-command
 -           ;; self-insert-command
 m           ;; self-insert-command
 a           ;; self-insert-command
 c           ;; self-insert-command
 r           ;; self-insert-command
 o           ;; self-insert-command
 <return>        ;; minibuffer-complete-and-exit
 m           ;; self-insert-command
 y           ;; self-insert-command
 -           ;; self-insert-command
 q           ;; self-insert-command
 u           ;; self-insert-command
 o           ;; self-insert-command
 t           ;; self-insert-command
 e           ;; self-insert-command
 <return>        ;; minibuffer-complete-and-exit
 M-x             ;; execute-extended-command
 g           ;; self-insert-command
 l           ;; self-insert-command
 o           ;; self-insert-command
 b           ;; self-insert-command
 a           ;; self-insert-command
 l           ;; self-insert-command
 -           ;; self-insert-command
 s           ;; self-insert-command
 e           ;; self-insert-command
 t           ;; self-insert-command
 -           ;; self-insert-command
 k           ;; self-insert-command
 e           ;; self-insert-command
 y           ;; self-insert-command
 <return>        ;; minibuffer-complete-and-exit
 C-M-b m         ;; self-insert-command
 y           ;; self-insert-command
 -           ;; self-insert-command
 q           ;; self-insert-command
 u           ;; self-insert-command
 o           ;; self-insert-command
 t           ;; self-insert-command
 e           ;; self-insert-command
 <return>        ;; minibuffer-complete-and-exit
 <escape> <escape> > ;; end-of-buffer
 C-M-b           ;; my-quote
 ;; self-insert-command
 C-h l ;; view-lossage
```